# Volatility calculation for intra-day cash-or-nothing call binary option

Tags: volatility, binary-options, cash-or-nothing

Firstly, I do not have a quant finance background. This is new to me, and I imagine that this is a basic question for this group.

I am calculating the price of a binary/digital option with closed-form equations derived from a Black-Scholes analysis. More specifically, I am using the Black-Scholes valuation for a [Cash-or-nothing call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_option#Cash-or-nothing_call).

The option period that I have been asked to calculate ends every hour, on the hour. I am sampling the underlying every 5 seconds. How should I scale and/or calculate my volatility if I want to use the ['normal' approach](http://optionstradingbeginner.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/historical-volatility-part-2-formula-to.html) (but assuming a 0 mean). These are all annualised to one year. Should I still do the same?

More specifically, I am curious how I scale the standard deviation of the sum of the square log returns in this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly is meant by "microstructure noise"?](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2360/what-exactly-is-meant-by-microstructure-noise)

Comment: I suspect that this questions is about scaling volatility, not about noise.

Answer (score 1):

Black–Scholes usually assumes your time and volatility are annualised. Accordingly, when you calculate the volatility term you would usually annualise it to 252 or 260 (or however many trading days a year are applicable to your situation). Accordingly, the time remaining term of the Binary Option must also be expressed as a fraction of a year (again, 252, or 260, days or..). By way of example, if you have a 1 hour option just starting, this T term would be expressed as a year (1/no-hours-tradeable-year). As the option period passes, you would decrease the T term so it is always expressed as part of a year.

In summary, providing the way in which you scale volatility by time and the way you express your T term of the Black–Scholes are in the same, you'll be fine.